# MySQL. Select all from table which matches with regular expression template or nothing

Tags: mysql, regex

I've a such MySQL-request:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `shops` WHERE `shop_name` LIKE '%".$name."%';";
```

It searches records, which matches with regular expression template. But when it found nothing it returns all records. But I want it returns nothing in this case. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RLIKE operator of MYSQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)L

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `shops` WHERE `shop_name` RLIKE '%".$name."%';";
```

Comment: No - get rid of the percents, unless they are a necessary part of the search!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think, you send an epmty string to $name.
Because LIKE don't send all sets when a pattern doesn't match.
If $name is empty, query will be "SELECT * FROM `shops` WHERE `shop_name` LIKE '%%';". This query will be retrurns all sets from `shops`.

You need check $name for empty string before execute query, or use previous advice (RLIKE).